# IllegalState exception when the button is pressed for the second time

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I am making a simple android app. When I press the button in the main activity , i call the MoveBalloon activity. This activity uses the microphone to move an image in the screen based on the sounds that the mic detects. I press back button  and I return in the main activity. Everything goes well until I press the button for the second time to lunch the MoveBalloon activity again. At this moment the app crashes. I think the problem is in the MoveBallon.class but I dont know excatly what's wrong . Below I am posting the logcat and the MoveBalloon.class. Please help me ! Thank you in advance! 
Logcat :

```
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prova1/com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.example.prova1.Microphone.<init>(Microphone.java:29)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.onCreate(MoveBalloon.java:106)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-24 14:52:20.346: E/AndroidRuntime(23075):    ... 11 more
```

MoveBallon.class :

```
package com.example.prova1;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MoveBalloon extends Activity {
    Bitmap balloon;
    Bitmap background;
    Bitmap _background;
    int i,j,k;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    Bitmap foto;
    DrawBalloon myView;
    float x,y,sensorX, sensorY;
    SensorManager sm;
    Microphone mic;
    int width, height;
    int count=0;





public class DrawBalloon extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    SurfaceHolder ourHolder ;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning=true;

    public DrawBalloon(Context context) {
        super(context);
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.yeehaaa);
        ourHolder= getHolder();

    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning=false;
        while(true){
            try{
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread=null;
    }

    public void resume(){
        isRunning=true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();


    }
    @Override
    public void run (){

        while(isRunning){
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();


         if(canvas!=null){
            updateMic();
            canvas.drawBitmap(_background,0,0,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(balloon, sensorX, sensorY,null);
            checkCollisions(canvas);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
         }
        }
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*sm= (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!=0){
        Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this,s ,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }*/
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    i=intent.getIntExtra("b1", 0);
    j=intent.getIntExtra("b2", 0);
    k=intent.getIntExtra("b3", 0);

mic = new Microphone();
balloon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), i);
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), j);

DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels; 
sensorX=(width-balloon.getWidth())/2;
sensorY=height-balloon.getHeight()-20;

//x=y=sensorX=sensorY=0;


_background = getResizedBitmap(background,height,width);
myView= new DrawBalloon (this);
myView.resume();
setContentView(myView);
}

public void updateMic(){
double level = mic.getAmplitudeEMA();

    sensorY-=level;
}



public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // Create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // Recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    return resizedBitmap;
}



private void checkCollisions(Canvas canvas){

    foto=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), k);
        if(sensorY<=50&&sensorY>=40){


           canvas.drawBitmap(foto, (width-foto.getWidth())/2, 30, null);

           mp.start();
    }else{
        if (sensorY<40){
               canvas.drawBitmap(foto,(width-foto.getWidth())/2, 30, null);

        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.stop();
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Here is Microphone.class :

```
package com.example.prova1;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class Microphone {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    int level;
    static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;
    private double mEMA = 0;

    public Microphone(){
        // Audio recorder
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        mEMA = 0;
       try {
            recorder.prepare();
               recorder.start();

       }
          catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void stopMic(){

                recorder.release();


}
    public double getLevel(){
        level = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        level = level/2700;
        return level;
    }
    public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
        double amp = getLevel();
        mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
        return mEMA;
}

}
```

NEW LOGCAT:

```
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1680
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):    at com.example.prova1.Microphone.getLevel(Microphone.java:43)
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):    at com.example.prova1.Microphone.getAmplitudeEMA(Microphone.java:48)
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):    at com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.updateMic(MoveBalloon.java:157)
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):    at com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon$DrawBalloon.run(MoveBalloon.java:84)
```

Comment: The line number 29 in Microphone.class is :     recorder.start();

Comment: And the line number 106 in MoveBalloon.class is :                    mic = new Microphone();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, where class Micorphone comes from. Can you provide more information about this class?

BUt the problem seems to be probably in initialization of MediaRecorder inside Microphone class, when microphone is already recording.

Here you can see how to properly handle audio recording by using MediaRecorder: [Audio Capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html).

See [Real time Audio Capture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) for real time audio processing.

Generally, you had to stop and release media recorder, when back button is pressed. This allows you to init recorder later without error.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I posted Microphone.class . Thank you!

Comment: Try call mic.stopMic() in MoveBallon.onBackPressed() method. Also recorder.stop() before release in this method

Comment: I tried that. But now when I press back button the app crashes. The logcat is:

Comment: 09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1680
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):  at com.example.prova1.Microphone.getLevel(Microphone.java:43)
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):  at com.example.prova1.Microphone.getAmplitudeEMA(Microphone.java:48)
09-24 16:31:44.140: E/AndroidRuntime(31331):  at com.example.prova1.MoveBalloon.updateMic(MoveBalloon.java:157)

Comment: I posted again the logcat.

Comment: You are accesing getLevel() method after stopMic() method. You have to store values from getLevel() before stopMic is called() or use the value from getLevel() before stopMic is called